# PySpark .groupBy() and .count() slow on a relatively small Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

OK let me first describe how I create the `Dataframe` and what is in it.

I have one set of gziped HTML documents and one set of gziped Metadata to these HTML documents

For both I provide a list of Paths to an `RDDs` like this:

```
Wet_Paths_RDD = sc.parallelize(Wet_Paths)
Wet_RDD = Wet_Paths_RDD.map(open_wet_filelist).flatMap(split_wetfiles)
```

I prepare both RDDs in a way that a row looks like this:

```
(k,(some,other,values))
```

And then I join my meta data `RDD` with my content `RDD` together like this:

```
Wat_Wet_RDD = Wat_RDD.join(Wet_RDD)
```

and then I unpack the by now relative complex tuple and do among other things a language detection. I have to do a join of `RDDs` because up until now all my strings are represented as `byte strings` that can not be represented in a Dataframe.

```
Wat_Wet_RDD = Wat_Wet_RDD.map(unpack_wat_wet_tuple_and_decoding_and_langdetect)
```

I then transfer the joined `RDD` into a `Dataframe`:

```
wat_wet_schema = StructType([
    StructField("URI", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Links", StringType(), True),
    StructField("N_Links", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Content_type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Original_Encoding", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Content", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Language", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Language_confidence", IntegerType(), True),
])

WatWet_DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Wat_Wet_RDD, schema=wat_wet_schema)
```

and take a look at it with:

```
print(WatWet_DF.show(20))
```

Up until now everything takes 24 minutes but the next step:

```
print(WatWet_DF.groupBy(WatWet_DF.Language).count().orderBy(desc('count')).show(100))
```

I aborted after 24 hours without a single task in this stage solved.

At the moment I'm running the cluster on a single test linux VM. The VM has 4 Cores and is running the Master and the Worker at the same time. The Worker has 4 executioners each with 3.5G of memory. The Dataframe should be comprised of about 1 million rows. The Apache Spark Version is 2.1.0 and python 3.5 is used. The VM runs on top of a dated Xeon W3680 6(v12)core with 24G of RAM.

Comment: How many rows do you have in `WatWet_DF`?

Comment: It should be about give or take a million. `.count()` alone already takes a very long time. The `WatWet_DF.content` field contains a whole document so maybe that is the reason the `Dataframe` is slow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out why `.count()` and `.groupBy()` take so much longer than `.show()` on this data set. The reasons is that for `.count()` and `.groupBy()` to provide results all, functions that are executed in the map phase here `Wat_Wet_RDD.map(unpack_wat_wet_tuple_and_decoding_and_langdetect)` need to be applied to the whole data set. For `.show()` to provide results these functions only need to be applied to a subset of the whole data set providing results much faster. Now the map phase, `Wat_Wet_RDD.map(unpack_wat_wet_tuple_and_decoding_and_langdetect)` had some very expensive functions in it resulting in very long compute times especially when `.count()` and `.groupBy()` are compared to `.show()`.